# I need a python program to detect QR Codes in camera RAW files

Tags: python, opencv

I need to loop through a folder of camera raw (cr2) files and detect whether the image contains a QR Code and if so capture the data. I need to run this as an Automator program hopefully as a python script. I can do this with jpg or png files but I need to read camera raw. I'm new to Python and have tried to find a solution but came up empty. All the solutions I can file read jpg or png files not RAW. Can anyone help?

I've tried the python cv2 library which works fine on jpg or png files but gets an error that the image is empty when reading Canon camera raw file.
All of the solution I can find only work on jpg, png, or video files

Comment: so, as you notice, you need to supply your own functionality to read these files, instead of relying open opencv's `imread`. So, what have you tried in that direction?

Comment: I don't know where to begin with providing functionality to read the files.  Any suggestions?

Comment: yes. look for a library that can read your image format of interest, and then figure out whether the data structure it reads into can directly be used by cv2 or needs to somehow be converted.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was fixed by flipping the image. While my iPhone camera could detect the QR Code data on the converted file, the cv2 detector could not.  When I added a line of code to flip the image the detector worked fine.

```
import os
from os import listdir
import cv2
from PIL import Image

#convert camera raw image to jpg
im = Image.open("JBS_9036.CR2")
rgb_im = im.convert('RGB')
rgb_im.save('JBS_9036.JPG')


#read the converted image
image = cv2.imread("JBS_9036.JPG")
mirrored_image = cv2.flip(image, 1)


#initalize the cv2 QRCode detector
detector = cv2.QRCodeDetector()

# detect and decode
data, bbox, straight_qrcode = detector.detectAndDecode(mirrored_image)

#show results
# if there is a QR code
if bbox is not None:
    myData = (f"{data}")
    print(f"QRCode Found data= {data}")

else:
    print("No QR Code Found")
```